Will SpaceX stop selling Falcon 9 and Falcon Heavy launches once Starship is operational?
SpaceX is currently in the process of testing their new Starship rocket. Starship is expected to be both cheaper than and have a higher payload capacity than both Falcon 9 and Falcon Heavy and SpaceX has said that it will replace Falcon 9 and Falcon Heavy. However, they have also said that it might take 6-8 years. Does SpaceX plan to stop selling Falcon 9 and Falcon Heavy launches once Starship is operational and there are enough vehicles to take over the work of those rockets? Or, do they plan to continue selling them until either no one will buy them because Starship is much cheaper, they run out of boosters (assuming they stop making more), or until all of their current sold launches are complete?

Jumbo jets didn't put Cessna out of business. And the A380 has failed to displace its 55 year old 747 competitor. Bigger is not better for every application. There is a wide variety of payload mass and orbital inclinations. Falcon Heavy has had only 6 commercial launches since its debut 6 years ago. Other than SpaceX itself, there is a small proportion of payloads requiring super heavy  launch capability.

@Woody If a jumbo jet was potentially almost 300 times cheaper than a Cessna, Cessnas would be very very very rare. Starship could cost as low as $10 per kilogram when reused. If this happens, that would mean that it would be cheaper to purchase a dedicated mission for a satellite than to fly it on Falcon 9. And not by a small amount, I'm talking 58 times here

My point was that a Jumbo cannot fill the role of a Cessna. And visa versa.

@Woody I am certain that if a Cessna flight cost 300 times that of a Jumbo flight, people would try to find a way to either use Jumbos, or make cheaper Cessnas

@Starship again, different products for different markets. A Cessna can go places a 747 can't, can be operated by people who can't operate a 747. Reverse is in part also true, 747 has more range than the longest range Cessna and can carry a lot more. And the same is true for F9 and Starship. It'll be cheaper to operate Starship for launching 100 tons than launching 10 F9s with 10 tons each, but if you only need to launch 5 tons it'll be overkill and more expensive to use Starship. Same reason Electron survives in a market containing F9. And why Cessna survives in a market containing Boeing.

@jwenting  Electron would not survive if purchasing an entire Falcon 9 cost 58 times less than purchasing an election (not cost per kilo, i'm talking you got the whole rocket)

@Starship irrelevant. It doesn't and can't. And Starship (including the entire cost of a launch, manpower, fuel, recovery cost etc. etc. isn't going to cost 1/58th that of a Falcon 9, it'll always be more expensive per launch but cheaper per ton once you're over a certain tonnage per launch).

It's almost always better to have a tool that's fit for the job than to try to use something that only kind of works. Starship may replace SOME uses of Falcon Heavy, but it seems very unlikely that such a huge lift vehicle could become cheap enough to pick up a lot of those smaller jobs.

Gwynne Shotwell, second in command to Elon Musk at SpaceX says that she expects to keep selling Falcon 9's for about 8 more years or so (basically end of ISS + a couple of years just in case), before Starship entirely replaces it in the session she did at the Baron Capital Conference, Nov 2024.

If you read the article I linked to it has the same quote...but that quote answers how long it will fly for, not how long it will be sold for.

@Starship, the users guide suggests sales will stop 24 months in advance of the last paid flight.

@Mark add that as an answer

I guess she expects competitors to outcompete SpaceX by then in the small to medium launch vehicle market, not that Starship will be a viable alternative for every launch scenario currently used by F9.

As things stand I wouldn't bank on the competition doing much outcompeting.
